# Limit horizontally aligned buttons to 5 buttons then start new row

Tags: vb.net, button, alignment, width

I have a bit of a tricky question which I cannot figure out.

I have a tab page on that tab page exists a horizontal row of buttons, a row has 5 buttons. The end user is able to create X-amount of new buttons. what I want but cant figure out is how can I make horizontal rows of up to 5 buttons, no more. If the row has exceeded the limit of 5 buttons then a new row should be started underneath?

I have tried to capture all sorts of dimensions like tab page widths divided by (button + in between space) widths etc.

Is there a simple method to do this, using vb.net?

**EDIT:**

```
Public Class create_allined_rows

    Private Sub create_allined_rows_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim BTNCOUNT As Integer = Me.TabPage1.Controls.Count
        MsgBox("There are " & BTNCOUNT & " buttons currently on tabpage1.")

        Dim numofrows As Integer = Math.Ceiling(BTNCOUNT / 5)
        MsgBox("there should be " & numofrows & " on this form...")

        MsgBox("button 16 should be located in the " & numofrows & "st column...")

        MsgBox("button 17 should be located in the " & numofrows & "nd column...")

        MsgBox("thus button 16 dimentional location should be " & " ?x " & (numofrows * 100 + numofrows * 5) & "pix .")

        MsgBox("thus button 17 dimentional location should be " & " ?x " & (numofrows * 100 + numofrows * 5) & "pix .")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you provide some code of what you have done for now?

Comment: I can only count the total number of buttons on a form, not howmany in a horrizontally alined row         `Dim BTNCOUNT As String = Me.TabPage1.Controls.Count
        MsgBox("There are " & BTNCOUNT & " buttons currently on tabpage1.")` What I want is the count for per row.

Comment: what platform is this? WPF, winform, ASP.NET, other?

Comment: This should better demontraight my delema (Its a win form with one tabpage and 17 buttons on it...) (See EDIT for the relating code)

Comment: You can use a FlowLayoutPanel set to Horizontal direction.  Then make it just wide enough for 5 buttons.  The buttons will automatically be laid out.

Comment: cool I will have to look into that I wasnt even aware there was such thing as a FlowLayoutPanel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Explanation

It's quite easy! Look, you haven't provided your code and I can't say that what is the specific difficulty you are facing and how do you make new buttons!? I don't know. You can add a textbox which works in the background. And add one number every time a new button is created.

Then use the MOD operator and your work is done.

## Code and Example

```
Private Sub Form1_Load () Handles Form1.Load
      Textbox1.Visible = False 
      'Or you can write here Textbox1.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub AddButton_Click () Handles AddButton.Click
      Textbox1.Text = Val(Textbox1.Text) + 1
      If Val(Textbox1.Text) MOD 5 = 0 then
            'Code for moving to next line
      Else
            'The normal code you have written         
      End If
End Sub
```

Hope it works perfectly!

Comment: I was lead to the MOD function which I knew nothig of, this helped a great deal in my getting what I was trying to achieve :)